# Updating total price array when user submit

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with nested array in it like below.

```
cart ( 
[total] => 98 
[itemcount] => 3 
[items] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 ) 
[itemprices] => Array ( [0] => 33.00 [3] => 32.00 [5] => 33 ) 
[itemqtys] => Array ( [0] => 1 [3] => 1 [5] => 1 ) 
[iteminfo] => Array ( [0] => Chemistry [3] => Additional Mathematics [5] => Physics ) 
)
```

And I have the code below in a switch when the user enter correct discount code, this function will trigger. I can get it work to display the discounted price.

```
$anewvalue = 16.50;
$physubject = "Physics";
$index = array_search($physubject , $cart->iteminfo);
if (false !== $index) {
$cart->itemprices[$index] = $anewvalue;}
```

Problem is that how do I update the total whenever the user key in a correct discount code and submit the form, so that the total price will always up to date, because now it doesn't do that.

Comment: You will need to store that value somewhere. Flat file, Database etc

Comment: @andrewb Can I store it in session?

Comment: A users session? That will be destroyed when user logs out/leaves. Explain your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recalculate the total every time a correct discount is applied.

```
if (false !== $index) {
    $cart->itemprices[$index] = $anewvalue;
    //re-calculate the total
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($cart->itemprices as $key=>$itemprice) {
        $total += $itemprice * $cart->itemqtys[$key];
    }
    $cart->total = $total
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but do I need to put the foreach in everyone of the switch cases?

Comment: I am not really that sure, how you implement your switch case, but I assume you use the switch case for every different discount. If that's the case you can actually apply the total re-calculation after all the switch case is finished.